# SQL Server Express 2012 SocketException with Unity

Tags: sql-server, unity-game-engine

I've been having a connection problem with SQL Server Express 2012, I cannot seem to connect to it from Unity, I keep getting the error message:

> SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Code:

```
var connectionString: String =
      "Server=Jay\\MSSQLSERVER" +
      "Database=bfcrg;" +
      "User ID=Myuserid;" +
      "Password=mypassword;";

   var dbcon: IDbConnection;

   dbcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
   dbcon.Open();
```

I did do some research & I found out that people have been having this same issue with SQL Server Express 2008 & Unity getting the same `SocketException`.

As one person had suggested, I uninstalled the server which was installed as a named instance (`SQLExpress`) & re-installed it as the default instance (`MSSQLSERVER`). But yeah that didn't fix it.

I have also checked it with the Firewall turned off so no it's nothing to do with the Firewall.

However, I can connect to the Server with the SQL Server Management Studio so the server seems to be working fine I suppose.

So if anyone has any ideas, please let me know!

Cheers!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Connecting to the **default** instance should **not** require you to specify an instance name! E.g. you just use `server=.` or `server=(local)` (or specify the machine name) **without** an instance name.

Comment: There is no semicolon after your `Server=Jay\\MSSQLSERVER` part.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I thought as well, when accessing the default instance that you don't need to specify the instance name, but whenever I leaver the **server=machinename** or **server=localhost** or **server=127.0.0.1** or my **server=localip**, it throws another socketException saying **No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.**

Comment: & Petr, thanks for noticing that! I had it before but I guess I accidentally removed it & now when I try with the semicolon, with the instance name for the server, it says: **NotImplementedException: Mono does not support names pipes or shared memory for connecting to SQL Server. Please enable the TCP/IP protocol.**

What exactly should I do about that??

Comment: You should go into SQL server configuration manager, locate the SQL server network configuration section and enable the TCP/IP protocol for your instance, then restart the SQL server service

Comment: Just for having the tags set correctly: Are we talking about game programming using **Unity Game Engine aka Unity3D** or **Microsoft** Unity?

Comment: Kay, the tags are correct, we are talking about Unity3D, the Game Engine & connecting to  a MS SQL Server with it :)

& thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Another gotchya is The SQL Browser service being disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So this is what I figured out in the end, it didn't matter if I had the default instance installed but for some reason I still needed to specify the instance name followed by the machine name in the connection string.

& for the MS SQL Server Express 2012 to accept TCP/IP connections, you should go to the SQL Server Configuration Manager & click on the SQL Server Network Configuration on the left & click on Protocols for your server instance & change the TCP/IP disabled value to enabled & i should work just fine with Unity as long as you have the other necessary DLLs in place.

Thanks a lot everyone for the help!